# Modelsim Optimization Issue

Tags: optimization, verilog, modelsim

I am having problem when I am trying to run the following verilog code snippet in Optimized mode using Modelsim simulator v10.2c.

```
always @ *
  if (dut.rtl_module.enable == 1'b1)
    force dut.rtl_module.abc_reg = xyz;
```

If the above snippet is run in non-optimized mode, this works fine. But for optimized mode, it fails.

PS: I am using -O5 optimization level

Comment: How does it fail? is there a simple testharness that can be used to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Yeah, actually the intent of the snippet is to force a value on a wire inside an RTL block. But in case of optimization, the RTL gets all zero data.
Whereas, when I run the same code without optimization, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimisation typically disables access to simulator objects.  Your `force` command requires that access.

You'll need to explicitly enable access.  Unfortunately I can't see anything useful in the Modelsim AE documentation, however from Riviera-PRO:

```
 +accs
         Enables access to design structure. This is the default in -O0,
         -O1 and -O2 and may optionally be specified for -O3. If omitted,
         the compiler may limit read access to selected objects.
```

Modelsim supports `+acc`, it just doesn't appear to be well documented.  The only reference appears to be this suggestion:

```
While optimization is not necessary for class based debugging, you might want to use 
vsim -voptargs=+acc=lprn to enable visibility into your design for RTL debugging.
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was wondering that why forcing fails in Optimization?

Comment: @user3733015 One of the optimisations performed by the simulator prevents access (via `force`) to internal objects.  This optimisation is simulator dependent - maybe they can improve speed by avoiding a table lookup internally.  Either way, if you want to access objects *and* have full optimisation, you need to tell the simulator so it keeps this functionality available to you.  Sometimes it's possible to configure access just for certain objects or classes of objects.